# Browser not caching image sent via PHP

Tags: php, image, caching

I'm trying to force the browser to cache an image for as long as possible but it's not working, the browser always requests a new image. My current code is like this:

```
session_cache_limiter('');

$gifData = "\x47\x49\x46\x38\x37\x61\x1\x0\x1\x0\x80\x0\x0\xfc\x6a\x6c\x0\x0\x0\x2c\x0\x0\x0\x0\x1\x0\x1\x0\x0\x2\x2\x44\x1\x0\x3b";
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
header("Expires: " . gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time() + 365 * 86440));
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=31556926, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: cache");
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($gifData));
echo $gifData;
```

And in the browser I get this:

**Request headers:**

```
Request URL:http://example.com/track/8c0343920ff823148261ef1cc70e74b5_4_123.gif
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:example.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
```

**Response headers:**

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31556926, pre-check=10800
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:35
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Mon, 12 May 2014 23:31:49 GMT
Expires:Wed, 13 May 2015 03:35:09 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:cache
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/   5.5.3-1ubuntu2.2
```

So as far as I can see all the response headers seem correct, yet the browser keeps asking for the image. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: If you hit Refresh on the image itself, the browser will still send another request.

Comment: @Jack, yes that was it, I was hitting refresh directly on the image and expecting the browser to use the cached version. Thanks for the info. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jake pointed out, the issue was that I was hitting refresh on the image itself, which means the browser was not using the cache at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use something such as `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']`, which tells the browser to use the cached version of the image `$gifData` if the timestamp hasn't changed.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) 
       && 
  (strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == filemtime($gifData))) {
  // send the last mod time of the file back
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($gifData)).' GMT', 
  true, 304);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this at some point but I'm not actually getting any `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` from the browser.